# Miktex font errors

Tags: fonts, miktex

I use miktex 2.9

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{pxfonts} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{eqnarray}
p(y)=\frac{\kappa b^{\lambda}}{\Gamma(\lambda)}e^{-by^{-\kappa}}y^{-(\kappa\lambda+1)}.
\end{eqnarray}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I got the following errors:

> Running miktex-makemf.exe... miktex-makemf: The rpxmi source file
>   could not be found.
>
> Running ttf2pk.exe... miktex-makepk: PK font rpxmi could not be
>   created.  ) (see the transcript file for additional information)
>   !pdfTeX error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
>   2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.EXE (file  rpxmi): Font rpxmi at 360 not found  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced! texify: pdflatex failed for some reason (see log file).

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: remove \usepackage{txfonts} and \usepackage{pxfonts} solve the problems. I finally figured it out!

Comment: Removing the font packages perhaps avoid the error but not is not really a solution. Try if it helps if you run on a command line (as user ) `updmap`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is solved himself by OP.