# Windows 10 - MikTex 2.9 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font jkpmn8t+10

Tags: errors, miktex

I had to reinstall my Windows 10 machine and now the Tex document that I'm working does not compile and I have the error `source file not found`.

I tried to :

1. Remove and ReInstall Miktex (32 or 64 bits)-> Same problem
2. Install to multiple users or to a single user and with package installation on the fly and with different user profiles-> Same Problem
3. Perform Miktex Update and Repository sync after installation -> Same problem
4. Full Miktex installation -> Same Problem

---

### output of command: `latex file.tex`

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex\latex\kpfonts\t1jkp.fd")Running miktex-makemf.exe...

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason:

  The jkpmn8t+ source file could not be found.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
Running hbf2gf.exe...

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)

Couldn't find `jkpmn8t+.cfg'

Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed for the following reason:

  No creation rule for font jkpmn8t+10.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

! Font csnameendcsname=jkpmn8t+10 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file no
t found.
<to be read again>
                   relax
l.270 \begin{document}
```

---

### output of `miktex-maketfm.log`

```
2016-01-06 00:59:13,607Z INFO  makex - Running hbf2gf.exe...
2016-01-06 00:59:13,966Z FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font jkpmn8t+10.
```

---

### output of `pdflatex file.tex`

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mkbibnameprefix {e}\isdot \ifprefchar
                                                  {} {} {\ifuseprefix {\bibn...
l.303 \printotherlists
                        % If option 'otherlistsat=back', print other lists o...
```

Comment: Welcome! MikTeX does not always complete the installation of fonts correctly. Sometimes, you have to update the `.map` files afterwards. However, I don't use MikTeX. You need to run `updmap` but you should probably wait for somebody to advise you how to do it who uses that distribution.

Comment: OK. You need to run `updmap` on the command line as user. I found a [comment from somebody who knows MikTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283134/miktex-font-errors?rq=1#comment682805_283134) on another question. If that doesn't help see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53808/miktex-font-ccicons-at-600-not-found?rq=1) but I doubt that you need the solution there as I would be surprised if the package for this font was buggy.

Comment: The name of the missing font (`jkpmn8t+10`) seems to suggest that you are using `microtype`'s automatic font expansion in DVI mode, which won't work.

Answer (score 1):

run `updmap` on the command line as user solves my problem.

Comment: This worked for me!